# Trouble passing information through segue

Tags: objective-c

Alright. I'm having trouble passing data through a segue from one UITableViewController to another. The proper information does not load. Without a bunch of endless talk about the setup, here goes:

On the upper (passing) viewController side:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"deriv"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView2 indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DerivationController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.derivationName = [equationsList2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

On the receiving viewController side:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"derivCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [derivations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [details objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

- equationsList2 is a list of equations in an NSArray instance. Depending on which one is selected, cell.textLabel and cell.detailTextLabel are set accordingly from NSArrays "derivations" and "details".
- The declaration for DerivationController.h is on the passing viewController's header list.
- No errors are thrown.

Any ideas?

Code for setting 'derivations' and 'detail':

```
if ([_derivationName isEqualToString:@"Momentum-Velocity"])
{
    // Equation 1:
    derivations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Momentum",
                   @"Mass",
                   @"Velocity",
                   nil];
    details = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"Momentum units in kg ∙ m/s",
               @"Mass units in kilograms (kg)",
               @"Velocity units in meters/second (m/s)",
               nil];
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `setDerivationName` in your receiver view controller? And also the code where you set the properties `derivations` and `details` in the receiver VC.

Comment: Is the name of the segue really 'deriv' in your storyboard?'

Comment: You haven't stated the problem yet. Your `prepareForSegue` method appears to be passing a string value to a `derivationName` property. Is that string not getting passed?

Comment: @JonathanArbogast I fail to see the significance of that is. It's shorthand for 'derivation'.

Comment: @TimothyMoose That's exactly the issue.

Comment: @BlackRider Edited it in

Comment: The name of the segue in your code needs to match the name of the segue in your storyboard.  Otherwise, you won't enter that if statement and that string won't get passed to the destination view controller

Comment: @JonathanArbogast I mistook your wording for disbelief at the name. The name of the segue is 'deriv' indeed in Storyboard.

Comment: Is that the 'whole' setter for derivationName? Did you assign the new value to _derivationName before making that check and is it indeed equal to "Momentum-Velocity"?

Comment: The full code is 42 instances (equations) of if/else if/else loopings to generate the proper NSArray texts. You lost me on the last part; I'm still trying to grasp Obj-C.

Comment: A good starting point would be to put breakpoints in each of the bits of code you've included here and inspect what's going on in the debugger when you trigger the segue. The goals is to find the first thing (chronologically) that isn't what you expect and then figure out why. For example, you might find break points not getting hit in the order you assumed or at all, properties that you think are set but are `nil`, etc. Narrow it down for us and report back.

Comment: Also, provide more context in your question. For example, the code where you say "Code for setting 'derivations' and 'detail'" is essentially useless because we don't know what method it's in. Its better to provide more code than not enough. If you can't solve the problem yourself, don't assume you know which pieces of code are relevant.

Comment: First of all, I don't see anything in the debugger even when breakpoints are enabled, the only thing I see is a warning about an iAd framework function not being called, but that's a separate issue entirely. Second of all, I'm not assuming I know which lines of code are relevant or not. That segment is under viewDidLoad, which because it is being passed to another VC, I'd tend to think was pretty obvious.

Comment: Which, I did solve the problem myself, so thanks for the spur.